# Order pie chart slices in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I want to order my pie chart labels and slices. My attempt below was able to order the labels, but the slices are still unordered. Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
data = structure(list(Stage = c("Collecting Applications", "Interview Stages", 
"Offer Accepted", "Offer in Progress", "To Open"), N = c(17L, 
30L, 8L, 2L, 65L), Prop = c(14, 25, 7, 2, 53), Label = c("14%", 
"25%", "7%", "2%", "53%")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

data$Stage = factor(data$Stage, ordered = TRUE, 
                      levels = c("To Open", "Collecting Applications", "Interview Stages", "Offer in Progress", "Offer Accepted"))

library(dplyr)
data = data %>% 
    mutate(end = 2 * pi * cumsum(N)/sum(N),
           start = lag(end, default = 0),
           middle = 0.5 * (start + end),
           hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, 1, 0),
           vjust = ifelse(middle < pi/2 | middle > 3 * pi/2, 0, 1))
data = data[order(data$Stage), ]
  
  
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data) + 
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                     start = start, end = end, fill = Stage)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = 1.05 * sin(middle), y = 1.05 * cos(middle), label = Label,
                  hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.4),  # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                       name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.2, 1.2),      # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                       name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
    theme_void() +
    labs(title = paste0("Progress for ", sum(data$N), " Positions"),
         fill = NULL) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix, the order data frame line needs to be before the hjust and vjust mutations. Although not entirely sure of the reasoning behind it. Would appreciate an explanation if someone knows. Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
data$Stage = factor(data$Stage, ordered = TRUE, 
                      levels = c("To Open", "Collecting Applications", "Interview Stages", "Offer in Progress", "Offer Accepted"))
data = data[order(data$Stage), ]
data = data %>% 
    mutate(end = 2 * pi * cumsum(N)/sum(N),
           start = lag(end, default = 0),
           middle = 0.5 * (start + end),
           hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, 1, 0),
           vjust = ifelse(middle < pi/2 | middle > 3 * pi/2, 0, 1))
  
  
  
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)
  
ggplot(data) + 
    geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                     start = start, end = end, fill = Stage)) +
    geom_text(aes(x = 1.05 * sin(middle), y = 1.05 * cos(middle), label = Label,
                  hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5, 1.4),  # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                       name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.2, 1.2),      # Adjust so labels are not cut off
                       name = "", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL) +
    theme_void() +
    labs(title = paste0("Progress for ", sum(data$N), " Positions"),
         fill = NULL) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Comment: The data frame needs to be ordered early so that the `cumsum`s are summing numbers in the right order. However, you don't need `ordered = TRUE` in the `factor()` call - confusingly, all factors have an order for their levels, the `ordered = TRUE` is for special cases when you may want to use `<` or you want specific contrasts in a model.

Comment: If you'd like, you can keep it all in `dplyr` syntax with `data %>% mutate(Stage = factor(Stage, levels = ...)) %>% arrange(Stage) %>% mutate(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and tips!